# Best way to access information inside of another class with TCL?

Tags: get, tcl

Basically, I'm trying to create a get method for a tcl class that I have so that I can access data inside that class within a proc that isn't inside a class. For example, it would look like this:

```
itcl::class foo {

    set list []
    proc getFilterList {} {
        return $list 
    }
}

proc bar {} {
    set list itcl::foo::getFilterList 
}
```

But hilariously the the list contains the phrase "itcl::foo::getFilterList" so I'm obviously doing something wrong. Sorry if this is an obvious one, I just can't seem to figure it out.

In addition to following the selected answer, I also made my variable available at a global scale which works for me seeing as how from creation to manipulation I know exactly when my variable is being modified and when I can access it's values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
proc bar {} {
    set list [itcl::foo::getFilterList]
}
```

Comment: That got me farther! The get method claims that it "can't read $list: No such variable." Any reason why that may occur other than the obvious like syntax issues.

Comment: Straight procedures won't be able to see variables in the class/namespace unless you ask for them to be visible. Add `variable list` to `getFilterList`.

Comment: @DonalFellows The only problem with that, is that $list is modified in another method within the same class. I need to be able to return it after it's been manipulated.

Comment: You may wish to change what 'list' is.  If you _declare_ it as a variable (ie not in the function, but in place of the set command, then you can access it through cget and configure built-in methods.